# Can't map an object, fetching an api returns first undefined then the object

Tags: reactjs

I'am fetching an api, but i can't map it because while console.log the object first i get undefined as response then i get the object.
This leads to this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.
I don't know why this happens, i search for it but could't find the solution.

[image]

My code:

```
const [UsersRow, setUsersRow] = React.useState()
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("api/machine", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + window.localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
      },
    })
      .then(resp => {
        return resp.json();
      })
      .then(data1 => {
        setUsersRow(data1);
      })
      .catch(error => {

        window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
        window.location.replace("/");
      })

  }, []);

{console.log(UsersRow)}

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h1>Azure machines</h1>
      <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="left">name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">resource_group</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {UsersRow.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name + row.resource_group}>
              <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
                <StyledButton size = "small" className={style.size3}>
                     <Link  style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'inherit'}} to={`/machines/${row.resource_group + "/" + row.name}`}>{row.name}</Link>
                  </StyledButton>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.resource_group}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you initially defined `UsersRow` as `undefined`, to fix that change this `const [UsersRow, setUsersRow] = React.useState()` to `const [UsersRow, setUsersRow] = React.useState([])`. This will set the initial state to empty array. Do a check for `UsersRow` length and then do `map` function on it, like `{UsersRow.length && UsersRow.map(....)}`

and change the code below

```
{UsersRow.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name + row.resource_group}>
              <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
                <StyledButton size = "small" className={style.size3}>
                     <Link  style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'inherit'}} to={`/machines/${row.resource_group + "/" + row.name}`}>{row.name}</Link>
                  </StyledButton>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.resource_group}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            ))}
```

to

```
{UsersRow.length > 0 && UsersRow.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name + row.resource_group}>
              <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
                <StyledButton size = "small" className={style.size3}>
                     <Link  style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'inherit'}} to={`/machines/${row.resource_group + "/" + row.name}`}>{row.name}</Link>
                  </StyledButton>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.resource_group}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            ))}
```

Comment: This solution works, but when loading the page first it appears an 0 then it appears the values.

Comment: @PatrickJosé thats because we need to add `UsersRow.length > 0`, just `UsersRow.length` will print the length there. Updated the answer. Please update your code also. If you like my answer, please mark as accepted and an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because setState is not reflected immediately and therefore you are initially attempting to map over undefined. You can do a check on your UsersRow variable before attempting to map.

```
<TableBody>
  {UsersRow && UsersRow.map(row => (
     <TableRow key={row.name + row.resource_group}>
        <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
          <StyledButton size = "small" className={style.size3}>
               <Link  style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'inherit'}} to={`/machines/${row.resource_group + "/" + row.name}`}>{row.name}</Link>
           </StyledButton>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{row.resource_group}</TableCell>
     </TableRow>
    ))}
</TableBody>
```